# Comment php with doxygen @file command not allow display comments

Tags: php, doxygen

I'm having trouble commenting on the php code with doxygen.

To recognize the following code I have to use ';' which changes the application source code.

```
if(){}; // Here the ;

switch(){}; // Here the ;
```

Is there any other solution to this problem?

(edited)

Comment: Usually, Doxygen is used to document method and functions, classes and interfaces, and 'everything API'. The actual implementation is just commented regularly in PHP as who ever uses your library or methods just needs to know the API, and not the internals.

Comment: Thanks Shi for comment